# How do they make such realistic graphics and environment in 3D game?

Tags: graphics, game-engine, 3d-modelling

I have always been mesmerized by the 3D environments of a game and how everything, every action look so real. I am a programmer. So I know how difficult it is! And I also know that people use some modelling or that kind of softwares to design. But someone has to make those softwares, right? What do they study to make those unbelievable  softwares? Which is their background? Mathematics or programming? Which branch of mathematics is so important for this?

Comment: it depends on techniques and HW used to achieve them. Majority uses combination of Bump mapping + various lighting schemes. If you want real looking output then post-processing is a must adding shadows and atmospheric scattering or volumetric fog. For most of this you need vector math and linear algebra. For physics side Newton/D'Lamberd physics is the way (numerical integration per time step which is simple `+=` in most cases). And do not forget the sound too it is really important.

Answer (score 3):

I think that most people who write graphics software do it because they were inspired by computer graphics.  As such, they generally have a background in programming.

That's a good thing, because the math you need is not so difficult... some discrete math, some vector algebra, and a little calculus.  The computer science and practical programming experience you need (optimization is a big thing in graphics) is much more difficult.  It also helps to know a little physics.  It also helps if you have some artistic talent.  You'll need to learn some color theory too.

As for what to study, well, it starts with lots of books and examples.  Graphics are *cool*, so lots of people love to share their code and their knowledge.  All you really have to do is get interested in *one thing*, do a google search, and you'll find a whole lot of links to lots of other interesting things in graphics.  Try "ray tracing code" or "perlin noise code", for example.

The more you learn, the more you want to learn.  You'll end up with a big list of questions and problems, and then you should go looking for books.  Back when I was getting inspired about graphics, I really liked the "Graphics Gems" series by Academic press, for example, but Imagine that the kids have different preferences these days.

And when you start getting *awesome*, you'll want to get yourself an ACM Digital Library subscription and start reading SIGGRAPH conference procedings.   Almost *every single cool thing* that was ever invented in computer graphics has been published in SIGGRAPH proceedings: http://www.siggraph.org/